# Where should I ask users which layout they prefer?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am designing a chart, and I have a few layout options that I'm considering.

I want to ask some people which they believe would be more beneficial to the users. I feel like this would be constructive, because I'm looking for answers with justifiable responses, not a discussion. That is, I'm looking for an answer like

> I think you should choose option A, because it would be more valuable to see only the newest data, rather than having to page through old data to find what I'm looking for.

Where should I ask this question?

Comment: Doesn't strike me as being able to be asked anywhere, it's "not constructive" no matter *where* on the network you post it.

Comment: I think it would be constructive. I believe that my question is the kind of [good subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) that makes it so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really it sounds like you need something like [Usaura](http://usaura.com/), a simple online usability testing solution where you can present many sort of tests, including simple A/B "which layout do you prefer" tests.

[User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com) can help you design specific, constructive design questions, but we're neither a user testing site nor a critique site. We do have plenty of questions that can help you learn how to conduct (formal or informal) [usability testing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability-testing?sort=votes&pagesize=30) and [user research](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-research).

Comment: I'll remove my answer, as you are clearly in better place than I am to talk about the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the help understanding just what UX.SE is about. I've posted my question there.